# Multiple sticky footers

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, scroll

Is there a solution to have multiple sticky footers, one per section/div ?

Assume the following example:

```
<nav id="stickyHeaderMenu"> 
   <!-- link_to section#one -->
   <!-- link_to section#two -->
   <!-- link_to section#three -->
</nav>

<section id="one"> 
   <div class="content"> </div>
   <nav id="footerNavOne"> </nav>
</section>

<section id="two"> 
   <div class="content"> </div>
   <nav id="footerNavTwo"> </nav>
</section>

<section id="three"> 
   <div class="content"> </div>
   <nav id="footerNavThree"> </nav>
</section>
```

The idea is to have one sticky header menu, and one sticky menu for the section in view at bottom of page. User scrolling down causes footer to change, depending on the section in view.

Note that sections are really tall, and take some scrolling to see all of it.

So when viewing `section#one`, `nav#footerNavOne` is the sticky footer. Once user reaches end of `section#one`, `nav#footerNavOne` sticks to it and goes up and out of page with it. Now `section#two` comes up, and `nav#footerNavTwo` becomes the new sticky footer.

---

update: I found the following, which looks pretty efficient: [sticky-kit.js](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/).

It sticks a div to the top of its parent. see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRE7Y/1/), showing it done on above example.

Is it possible to do the opposite: (stick the div to the bottom of parent) ?

Comment: Could you post a link to a page with the issue?

Comment: "When scrolling down and getting to end of the section, section_footer sticks to bottom of that section and goes out of page with it." is hard to understand, can you rephrase it and post a jsfiddle or a link to the page?

Comment: Just updated the description with a scenario.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this? I see no javascript or evidence to suggest you have, it is of course possible but you are essentially just asking for an implementation here not asking a specific programming question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2J4Ar/